# Where is C# Windows Form Application main() function

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, windows-forms-designer

In C# Windows Form Application,

- I have another class **Race**.
- I want to declare an **Object** of **Race** class
- And access this **Object** when a button is clicked

.

**Race** class:

```
class Race
{
    int player;
    int position;
}
```

Object creation:

```
Race Obj = new Race();
```

Accessing Object:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Obj.position++;
    }
```

**The question is, where to create Race class Object, so i can access it when button is clicked?**

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just make it PUBLIC. "class Race" is equal to "Private class Race"

Comment: @MajkeloDev The default access for a class is internal not private.

Comment: Just to answer the actual question, the `Main` function is typically located in the Program.cs file in the root directory of your project.

Comment: @juharr You're right. It's private only if it's a nested class

Comment: I wonder if we should get into dependency injection here... Might be overkill for the OP. But I'd create the `Race` object in `Main()` and pass it to the the form's constructor.

Comment: Before anyone can click the button is the obvious answer. Standard place is the form's constructor, or to instantiate it if null in the event handler it self.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare it at the class level. In your case, that means it needs to be a field in your form:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Race race;

    public Form1()
    {
        race = new Race();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        race.position++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give you one, back nothing wrong with this answer, given the info supplied by the OP

Comment: Especially since it's essentially the same answer as the other one here, which didn't get downvoted.

Comment: @MatthewWatson And it was answered before the other answer :)

Comment: and you spelled Race with a c. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson And the code compiles, automatic win ;P

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a private member in the form class and instanciate it there.

So something like

```
public class Form1
{
    private Race Obj = new Rate();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Obj.position++;
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the class is accessible.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, changed the wording to **accessible**